# ImportError: cannot import name 'StringType'

Tags: python

I took some sample code that was made in the django version 1.8.4, and like Python 2.7 when transferred to 3 python all flown away and produced such an error, how to fix it?

```
\lib\site-packages\config.py", line 91, in <module>
        from types import StringType, UnicodeType
    ImportError: cannot import name 'StringType'
```

one piece of code where using stringtype (config.py)(in site-packages)

```
def writeValue(self, value, stream, indent):
        if isinstance(self, Mapping):
            indstr = ' '
        else:
            indstr = indent * '  '
        if isinstance(value, Reference) or isinstance(value, Expression):
            stream.write('%s%r%s' % (indstr, value, NEWLINE))
        else:
            if (type(value) is StringType): # and not isWord(value):
                value = repr(value)
            stream.write('%s%s%s' % (indstr, value, NEWLINE))
```

Comment: could you provide your code maybe? Thanks!

Comment: did you see where he is located?

Comment: Actually, you probably need to modify your code (porting it to python 3). To help you : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no `StringType` in Python3.

Try this instead:

```
 from types import *
 x=type('String')
```

To check the type of an object use:

```
type(x) is str
```

which gives : `True` in the given case.

---

Also, alter you code as suggested in the question comments by iFlo : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html

Comment: yep that's is work, but what about UnicodeType, how to fix?

Comment: Since there is no "backward compatibility" of some Python libraries, you should refactor your code. Please read the link suggested which would help you. I'm also trying to find something relevant this specific problem :)

Answer (score 0):

`StringType` is obsolete in python 3, `UnicodeType` is not available anymore as it's the built-in `str` from python3 right now.